# Dealing with the need to pass the root view model down to the children

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I tend to feel the need in my Knockout applications to pass along a reference of the root view model down to the sub view models. However, I don't like the fact that I then have a dependency that lies both ways: root has a list of children, and each child a reference to the root.

## The Scenario

Here's a typical example, a simplified version of real code I tend to get:

```
var PersonViewModel = function(dto) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable(dto.name);
    self.department = ko.observable(); // This is the culprit; how to fill this?

    // Etc: several more properties would live here.
};

var RootViewModel = function(dto) {
    var self = this;

    self.title = ko.observable(dto.title);

    // For simplicity's sake array items are not observable, but they could be.
    self.departments = ko.observableArray(dto.departments);

    self.people = ko.observableArray([]);

    for (var i=0; i < dto.people.length; i++) {
        var newPerson = new PersonViewModel(dto.people[i]);
        self.people.push(newPerson);
    }
};
```

This can be constructed as follows:

```
var data = {
    title: "My organization",
    people: [
        { name: "John", departmentId: 1 },
        { name: "Mary", departmentId: 1 },
        { name: "Barthus", departmentId: 2 },
        { name: "Goldie", departmentId: 3 }
    ],
    departments: [
        { id: 1, name: "IT" }, 
        { id: 2, name: "Sales" }, 
        { id: 3, name: "Finance" }
    ]
};

var root = new RootViewModel(data);
ko.applyBindings(root);
```

See also [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gw9fzvxd/).

The culprit lies with the `self.department` observable in `PersonViewModel`. The input for that constructor function is a dto, which only has a `departmentId`. However, I want to set the actual *department* into that observable, but the `PersonViewModel` has no access to the list of available departments.

It is **important to note that there will be 5 to 10 more parts like "department"**, which will become a problem for some of the solutions I've considered (see below).

## Considered Options

Here are some things I've considered to make this work.

### 1. Have the Root View Model amend the PersonViewModel after creation

I can have the root model set the department for the created Person, for example by updating the for loop [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/gw9fzvxd/1/):

```
    for (var i=0; i < dto.people.length; i++) {
        var newPerson = new PersonViewModel(dto.people[i]);
        var dept = self.departments().filter(function(x) { 
            return x.id === dto.people[i].departmentId;
        })[0];
        newPerson.department(dept);
        self.people.push(newPerson);
    }
```

Please don't mind the rather crude and unsafe way of finding the actual department, production code would be a bit more robust (and longer).

Some things I don't like about this is that a unit test to check if the dto's department value leads to a correctly filled `PersonViewModel.department` observable requires me to actually construct a *different* unit: the root view model.

### 2. Make PersonViewModel have the Root as a dependency

Since it's the Root that knows about available departments, I could also justify that `PersonViewModel` is dependent on it:

```
var PersonViewModel = function(dto, root) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable(dto.name);

    var dept = root.departments().filter(function(x) { 
        return x.id === dto.departmentId;
    })[0];

    self.department = ko.observable(dept);
};
```

This feels a bit like overkill though: there will be many things in Root with which a Person view model will have nothing to do. Which brings me to the next option:

### 3. Make PersonViewModel dependent on a list of departments

All we need really is the list of departments, so a slight variation of the previous option would be [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/gw9fzvxd/2/):

```
var PersonViewModel = function(dto, departments) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable(dto.name);

    var dept = departments.filter(function(x) { 
        return x.id === dto.departmentId;
    })[0];

    self.department = ko.observable(dept);
};
```

However, this will lead to a problem in more realistic scenarios: the constructor function for `PersonViewModel` will get a long list of dependencies. Which brings me to my final option:

### 4. Make PersonViewModel dependent on a facade or repository

We could have either a facade or repository to encapsulate the dependencies for a `PersonViewModel`, something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/gw9fzvxd/3/):

```
var OrganizationRepository = function(departments /* etc */) {
    // For simplicity's sake array items are not observable, but they could be.
    this.departments = ko.observableArray(departments);

    // More "related" entities will be held here, e.g. locations, projects, etc.
};

var PersonViewModel = function(dto, organizationRepository) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable(dto.name);

    var dept = organizationRepository.departments().filter(function(x) { 
        return x.id === dto.departmentId;
    })[0];

    self.department = ko.observable(dept);
};

var RootViewModel = function(dto) {
    // Abbreviated   
    self.organizationRepository = new OrganizationRepository(dto.departments);

    for (var i=0; i < dto.people.length; i++) {
        var newPerson = new PersonViewModel(dto.people[i], self.organizationRepository);
        self.people.push(newPerson);
    }
};
```

For the simple example here it feels like overkill, but in bigger applications this may be worth it? In any case, this brings me to:

## The Bottom Line

Which options are better than others? And did I miss any other options?

As a footnote, I'm trying to optimize here for testability, readability, and having my dependencies as light and "correct" as possible.

Comment: Why not get the department where you create the PersonViewModel and pass that aswell?

Comment: I wanted to highlight the issue, so I left out all the other observable properties the View Models would have. Think I'll edit the question to note that (without adding 100s of lines of code).

Comment: Btw, option 2 still has the problem you have in option 1, you need to construct the root view model for a unittest.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a viable option?

```
var PersonViewModel = function(person, department) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable(person.name);
    self.department = ko.observable(department);
};

var RootViewModel = function(dto) {
    var self = this;

    self.title = ko.observable(dto.title);

    // For simplicity's sake array items are not observable, but they could be.
    self.departments = ko.observableArray(dto.departments);

    self.people = ko.observableArray([]);

    for (var i=0; i < dto.people.length; i++) {
        var person = dto.people[i];
        var newPerson = new PersonViewModel(person, dto.departments[person.departmentId]);
        self.people.push(newPerson);
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, it certainly might help. It would be a definitive improvement over version 3 I had, though it would still suffer from some constructor over injection as in reality there are more instances of this "departments" problem. (Apologies, this wasn't entirely clear from the question, I edited and tried to clarify that bit after you commented on the question.)